# Show sort icon by default - ngx-datatable-column

Tags: angular, sorting, icons

I am using

```
    <ngx-datatable-column [flexGrow]="4" [sortable]="true" name="Name" prop="empName" [cellClass]="'text-left'" [headerClass]="'text-left'" [width]="450">
                                        <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                                            <span class="empName">{{value}}</span>
                                        </ng-template>
                                    </ngx-datatable-column>


 ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.fetchDetails();
  }

  fetchDetails() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[0].classList.add("datatable-iconCustom");
  }
```

Here, the sorting icon is enabled when we click on header title. Is there a way to enable sorting icon by default at all times, not just on hover of title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ngx-datatable create icon dynamically. Its inital part is

```
<span class="sort-btn"></span>
```

after you clicked return to

```
<span class="sort-btn sort-asc datatable-icon-up"></span>
```

so you can't show or hide with css changing. You need to add these two clases dynamically or you need to trigger to click.

Code below add classes to first header as down icon. `sort-asc` and `datatable-icon-up` are for asc sort you should use another class if your default sort is descending

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[0].classList.add("sort-asc");
document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[0].classList.add("datatable-icon-up");
```

another way is trigger to click

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[0].click();
```

if you want to show both icon then u need custom class

in `style.css` put

```
.datatable-iconCustom:before {
    content: "\66 \65";
}
```

and add custom class rather than above two class

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[0].classList.add("datatable-iconCustom");
```

Comment: you can do it after u filled data . https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxdatatable-sort-test-nwlqf3

Comment: How to show both sort icons(both asc and desc icons ) on first load after the data is filled , before click is triggered.

Comment: Can you please add the custom class solution to stackblitz as its not working for me

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxdatatable-sort-test-7x2dfh I added

Comment: Its not updated. I need to show both the icons on initial load of the data for all the headers. Not just the first column header. And show only one icon after the header is clicked.

Comment: Last stackblitz show both f and e same time ? Did u both updated style.css and component.ts ?

Comment: I get error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Comment: Are you taking this in stackblitz or in your code ?

Comment: In my code..i have added the same sort of logic. but it doesnt work..edited the question with  my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214761/discussion-between-pc-coder-and-nancy).

Comment: I have added for loop to add both asc and desc icons to show on load, this works fine. i noticed a issue after click.For example, after intial load happens(we have asc and desc for all columns),when i click on Name column, asc sort arrow appears(this works fine). Then if i click on say Gender column, the default sort arrow(asc and desc arrow ) from Name column disappears( i dont see any arrow , this doesnt work fine). Is there a way to default back both the arrows for the previously clicked column after i click on some other column.

Answer (score 0):

You can add default unset icon like below:

```
.ngx-datatable { // datatable Style
  .datatable-header { // header Style
    .datatable-header-cell { // header Cell Style
      .sort-btn.datatable-icon-sort-unset::before { // Icon Style
        content: '\e968'; // You favorite Icon
        font-family: 'fontFamily'; // Your Font Family
        font-style: normal; // Font Style
     }
    }
  }
 }
```